# How to run 2 instances of ReactI18Next on the same app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am trying to run 2 instances of `React-i18Next` on the same application. I want parts of my application to be translated with `instance1` and parts of the application with `instance2`.

I've read about [createInstance](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#createinstance) and [i18nextprovider](https://react.i18next.com/latest/i18nextprovider#what-it-does) which I should use to create and run multiple instances. However, whatever I try I cannot seem to get it to work. I've also read [this thread on github](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/726) multiple times.

I have also created a codesandbox with my problem here: [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-framework-e9no1).

Whatever I try, I cannot seem to get this to work and I am now even wondering if this is even possible with react-i18Next? Could someone take a look at my codesandbox example and tell me if it is even possible what I am trying to do and if so, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work?

```
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
const { t: t2, i18n: i18n2: } = useTranslation();
```

The way the second `useTranslation()`'s variables are destructured rename the default variables so they can be used however you like to seperately.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't know how to 'import' or 'define' multiple instances. Because as of right now, when declaring importing both instances like so: `import "./i18n/instance1"; import "./i18n/instance2";` is not working.

Comment: You should only need to import once. I believe my answer will create two separate instances of React-i18Next.

Comment: Just tried it, getting the following warning "react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next"